# Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Not Found

Tags: solr, solrj

One of the surpirsingly few issues that did not have a resolution here (or anywhere for that matter).

This set up works perfect on my local. But fails to work on hosted server.

Thoughts?
Thanks in advance.
Kumar

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Error executing query
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:95)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:118)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.t0Solr_jsp._jspService(t0Solr_jsp.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Not Found

Not Found

request: http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/core0/select?q=primField: rockyBal&facet.field=dhomdhom&facet=true&facet.limit=1000&facet.mincount=2&rows=5000&wt=javabin&version=2
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:430)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:244)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:89)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: You're querying Solr with SolrJ from the same tomcat where Solr is running? Sure the port is correct? Don't you have one more error on your stacktrace more http client side?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes same server instance and Yes 8080 is correct.

Comment: No other errors. The above stack is from the client side.

Comment: Mind showing your solr.xml?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is raised here (CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:430)

```
  int statusCode = _httpClient.executeMethod(method);
  if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    msg.append( method.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase() );
    msg.append( "\n\n" );
    msg.append( method.getStatusText() );
    msg.append( "\n\n" );
    msg.append( "request: "+method.getURI() );
    throw new SolrException(statusCode, java.net.URLDecoder.decode(msg.toString(), "UTF-8") );
  }
```

So basically you are getting a 404 error code. Try to open a shell in that machine and type

> curl "...the url reported in the stack trace..."

I guess you will get the same error. Probably this has something to do with server binging port...

Probably Tomcat starts with a different binding port. Try to

- bind tomcat to 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 (just for testing)

or

- change your code by initialising the CommonsHttpSolrServer with the ip address / hostname of tomcat